# Problema con firefox y @font-face

Tags: css, html5, firefox

Hola Tengo un problema enlazando mis @font-face en firefox cunado uso "../" en la url de la font para ir al directorio anterior.

Tengo el siguiente codigo ejemplo, si quito el "../" y pego la carpeta "fuentes" que guarda todas mis fonts dentro del direcotiro donde esta el html funciona correctamente pero si dejo por fuera las fuentes en otra ruta que implique retroceder en el directorio Firefox no los toma.

Cabe mencionar que los otros navegadores si (chrome opera y hasta Explorer)

Agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar ya he mirado en muchas partes y en ningún lado he encotrado solución

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
            font-family: rock;
            src: local(rock), url('../fuentes/Rock_Salt (1)/RockSalt-Regular.woff');

            }
            p.custom_font{
            font-family: rock;
            font-size:52px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p class="custom_font">Hola Hola</p>
    <a href="../views 2/prueba2.html">volver</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te da algún error en la consola?

Comment: No ninguno solo cambia el tipo de font a Times New Roman

Answer (score 1):

Es por un problema de seguridad de [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) o [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), lo que dice es que: *los archivos sólo pueden leer ciertos otros archivos. Específicamente, un archivo puede leer otro archivo solo si el directorio principal del archivo de origen es un directorio antecesor del archivo de destino. Sin embargo, los directorios no se pueden cargar de esta manera.*

Por ende sólo tenés dos opciones de solucionar este problema:

1. O bien hacés como dijiste en la pregunta, movés la carpeta en el mismo directorio que tenés el archivo.
2. O habilitas el CORS para otros subdirectorios con `.htaccess`. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de qué headers escribir.

En el `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```