# No funcionan mis iconos en mozila firefox pero si en chrome

Tags: css, fuentes, icons

Tengo unos iconos de icoomon y no funcionan solo en chrome he cambiado la posicion de la etiqueta html para insertarlos y nada, le permiti a la web usar fuentes propias en la configuracion de mozila y nada, mi web esta en local.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>example </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Un excelente lugar para los amantes de la buena comida">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../letras.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../iconos/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="header__marca"><span class="marca__inicio">hola</span><span class="marca__medio">a</span><span class="marca__final">todos</span></h1>
      <address class="telefono"><span class="icon-Contactanos"></span>
        <p>Llamanos al xxxxxxxx</p>
      </address>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav__ul">
          <li class="nav__li icon-Conocenos"><a class="nav__a" href="Conocenos.html">Conocenos</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li icon-Multimedia"><a class="nav__a" href="Multimedia.html">Multimedia</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li icon-Contactanos"><a class="nav__a" href="Contactanos.html">Contactanos</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li icon-Preguntas"><a class="nav__a" href="Preguntas.html">Preguntas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="contenido" role="main">
      <article>
        <section class="articulo__contenido articulo__contenido--img" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <div class="articulo__contenido__titulo articulo__contenido--img__titulo"><span class="icon-diamante iconos"></span></div><img srcset="../img/Exclusividad500.jpg 300w,../img/Exclusividad500.jpg 600w,../img/Exclusividad1000.jpg 1000w,../img/Exclusividad1500.jpg 1500w">
          <p class="articulo__contenido__descripcion articulo__contenido--img__descripcion">Exclusividad.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="articulo__contenido articulo__contenido--img" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <div class="articulo__contenido__titulo articulo__contenido--img__titulo"><span class="icon-comida iconos"></span></div><img srcset="../img/Exclusividad.jpg 300w,../img/Comida.jpg 600w,../img/Atencion.jpg 1000w,../img/Postres.jpg 1500w">
          <p class="articulo__contenido__descripcion articulo__contenido--img__descripcion">Deliciosas Comidas.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="articulo__contenido articulo__contenido--img" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <div class="articulo__contenido__titulo articulo__contenido--img__titulo"><span class="icon-atencion iconos"></span></div><img srcset="../img/Exclusividad.jpg 300w,../img/Comida.jpg 600w,../img/Atencion.jpg 1000w,../img/Postres.jpg 1500w">
          <p class="articulo__contenido__descripcion articulo__contenido--img__descripcion">Atencion de primera.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="articulo__contenido articulo__contenido--img" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <div class="articulo__contenido__titulo articulo__contenido--img__titulo"><span class="icon-helado iconos"></span></div><img srcset="../img/Exclusividad.jpg 300w,../img/Comida.jpg 600w,../img/Atencion.jpg 1000w,../img/Postres.jpg 1500w">
          <p class="articulo__contenido__descripcion articulo__contenido--img__descripcion">Postres de otro nivel.</p>
        </section>
      </article>
      <article>
        <section class="articulo__contenido" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <div class="articulo__contenido__titulo"><span class="icon-ubicacion iconos"></span>
            <p>Ubicacion</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </article>
    </main>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p class="footer__titulo">hola q hace</p>
      <div class="divInfocontacto">   
        <address class="telefono"><span class="icon-Contactanos"></span>
          <p>gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
        </address>
        <address class="correo"><span class="icon-correo"></span>
          <p>ggggggggggggggggg</p>
        </address>
        <address class="ubicacion"><span class="icon-ubicacion">DIRECCIÓN</span>
          <p>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
        </address>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="../../ecma6/conocenos.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

este es el codigo ademas intente usar el modo seguro de firefox y no funciono de igual manera no cargaban los iconos

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?7ap6rt');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?7ap6rt#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?7ap6rt') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?7ap6rt') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?7ap6rt#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-Preguntas:before {
  content: "\e901";
}
.icon-Conocenos:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
.icon-Multimedia:before {
  content: "\e90e";
}
.icon-Contactanos:before {
  content: "\e942";
}
.icon-ubicacion:before {
  content: "\e948";
}
.icon-relog:before {
  content: "\e94e";
}
.icon-atencion:before {
  content: "\e976";
}
.icon-comida:before {
  content: "\e9a3";
}
.icon-circuloArriba:before {
  content: "\ea41";
}
.icon-circuloAbajo:before {
  content: "\ea43";
}
.icon-diamante:before {
  content: "\e904";
}
.icon-celular:before {
  content: "\e902";
}
.icon-diamond:before {
  content: "\e903";
}
.icon-helado:before {
  content: "\e905";
}
```

este es el estyle

Comment: Podrás compartir el css `style.css`? Creo que es un problema de rutas al llamar a la fuente en Firefox.

Comment: no sabes lo mucho que te aprecio por intenar ayudarme

Comment: En la consola te muestra algún error?

Comment: no solo unos relacionados a letras.css y al javascript, porque saque los archivos de la carpeta, pero borrando las etiquetas que referencean a estos archivos persiste el problema

Comment: Probá lo siguiente, en vez de poner esos estilos en una sub carpeta, ponelo en el mismo lugar que tenés el archivo html y contame si te funcionó. Porque puede ser que sea un problema de CORS de Firefox.

Comment: eres genial muchisimas gracias me funciono

Comment: Ahí te di una respuesta más detallada y de nada por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157636/problema-con-firefox-y-font-face/157744#157744) dí una respuesta similar a lo que te sucede a vos. Es un problema de CORS de Firefox. Podrías solucionarlo simplemente moviendo el archivo y la carpeta `.css` y `fonts/` respectivamente.

En vez de esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../iconos/style.css">
```

Probá cambiandolo a:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iconos/style.css">
```

Y mover el archivo `style.css` y la carpeta de las fuentes `fonts/`.